# MVVM, сложная логика во ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется WPF MVVM приложение, которое отображает разные геометрические фигуры (упростил для легкости изложения). Эти фигуры можно перемещать с помощью drag and drop и менять им z-order. Реализовал следующим образом:
Имеется MainViewModel, которое содержит IList. 
Также имеется MainView, который внутри Canvas отрисовывает ShapeView. 
Если запихнуть логику drag and drop и логику zindex внутрь MainViewModel, она становится не читаемой. Возникает вопрос, где должна храниться эта логика и кто должен содержать ссылки на ShapeViewModel? И как будет правильно ее реализовать с точки зрения MVVM?
Может, логика z-index должна находиться внутри модели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно унаследоваться от `ObservableCollection<T>`, назвать класс `ReorderableCollection<T> where T : IWithOrder, IWithPosition`, создать интерфейс `IWithOrder` со свойством `Order` (или `ZOrder`), аналогично с `IWithPosition`, разместить логику для изменения порядка и координат в этой коллекции. Или, если это нужно в одном месте, можно не городить иерархию и интерфейсы и просто сделать коллекцию `ShapeContainer : ObservableCollection<ShapeViewModel>`.

Comment: В этом случае логика drag n drop тоже будет в ShapeContainer? Насколько это верно?

Comment: @NikitaIlin Я бы не сказал, что это прямо-таки идеально чисто, но если работает, почему бы и нет? Как минимум, это улучшение над случаем, когда вся логика в MainVM. :) Если вас смущает, что SRP нарушается, то можете выделить "менялку порядка" и "драгалку фигур" в отдельные сущности и хранить их в MainVM. Тут зависит от того, насколько логика сложная, какие её части как собираетесь переиспользовать и т. п. Вариантов множество. Как минимум, изменение порядка я бы точно положил в коллекцию.

Comment: Спасибо! Я вот еще подумал: может, drag n drop это часть View и правильно ее вообще засунуть в code behind?

Comment: @NikitaIlin Вот code-behind как раз-таки лучше держать абсолютно пустым. Если считаете, что drag-n-drop в вашем случае реализуем без доступа к вью-моделям, то можно вытащить в логику в attached behavior, например. Если же логика зависит от вью-моделей, то и держать её по возможности надо там. Code-behind — последнее дело, когда уже больше ничто не помогает.